# ScrollView inside RelativeLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a LinearLayout and dynamically created elements in it. I need to make it scrollable if its height will be larger than 0.8 of screen's height. I'm trying to do it like that. Where is my mistake?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layoutContainer" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:baselineAligned="false" android:weightSum="1">


            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.85" >
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/alarmsLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >
            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.15">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/addAlarmBtn"
                android:src="@drawable/time"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your relative layout weight is 1 not 0.8, also Change the scrollview height to wrap_content. Also there is no parent layout. like with weight attr , you should have linear layout as parent

Comment: you are using LinearLayout as the parent Layout? If so, what is the weightSum you set to it?

Comment: just set listener on scrollview like this
[onTouchlistener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916506/animated-expandablelistview-in-scrollview/34916626#34916626)

Comment: Just add touchlistener like this [onTouchlistener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916506/animated-expandablelistview-in-scrollview/34916626#34916626)

Comment: @LevS : what is the problem with the layout appearance now?

Comment: @DAgrawal I also can't scroll it...

Comment: @DAgrawal maybe the problem is that height of ScrollView is 0dp by default? I logged it in code and it's 963 every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_weight="0.8" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/alarmsLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addAlarmBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/background_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where did you take this code? I have two RelativeLayouts. In first one I have a scrollView and in second one - ImageView

Comment: You dont need two relative layout. One is enough

Comment: The size of ImageView in your code is the full screen.

Comment: @LevS : check new ans

Comment: It's just like my code looks now. But it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width"match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/alarmsLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/addAlarmBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/time" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/alarmsLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addAlarmBtn"
    android:src="@drawable/badge" />
</RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```