# GridView inside CardView not scrolling

Tags: android

I am using cardView as parent layout and inside that I am using a gridView to display images. But when I try to scroll the gridView , the entire cardview scrolls.

This is my xml file :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/sportsGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/hundredfifty_dp"
        android:background="@color/counter_text_color"
        style="@style/scrollbar"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/five_dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: checkout my answer to this [Ques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916506/animated-expandablelistview-in-scrollview/34916626#34916626)

Comment: Sorry! It does'nt work

Comment: Use this `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` instead of `Grid View`. In this `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` use property `android:scrollbars="vertical"`.